# Reactive Extensions (RX) Custom Scheduler C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is is possible to build a custom scheduler that can inspect the value of every element passing through the IObservable, in order to decide on which thread to process the item?

I have a requirement to process items with the same key sequentially but different keys in parallel. It would make sense to have RX do the scheduling rather than have to leave the observable earlier than I'd like in order to allocate each value to a thread.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `GroupBy` followed by `ObserveOn`?

Something like:

```
source
    .GroupBy(item => item.Key)
    .SelectMany(group => group
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread)
        .Select(item => process(item))
    )
    .Subscribe(processResult => ...);
```

This will partition the stream by key, start a new thread for each key, and run `process()` for each item in that key.

Comment: That's very good. I just ran a test in LINQPad and it works beautifully. I must use this sometime.

Comment: elegant but what if there are thousands of keys? Ideally a scheduler could process items with the same key sequentially using tasks on threadpool threads?

Comment: Sure. You might want to use `Scheduler.Default` instead, which would use the threadpool or Tasks depending on your platform.

Comment: @Brandon Wouldn't using `Scheduler.Default` violate the requirement to process items with the same key sequentially?

Comment: it shouldn't...`ObserverOn` won't schedule more than one item at a time.  This is basically setting up a bunch of parallel `ObserveOn` queues.  The scheduler is used to schedule each `ObserveOn` instance to drain its queue.

Comment: @Brandon Ah ok, I wasn't sure whether `ObserveOn` would schedule things concurrently.

Comment: What I found was it didn't matter which scheduler I used (NewThread, TaskPoolScheduler, ThreadPoolScheduler) a different thread was used to process items of each key, so for 500 keys, I saw 500 different thread ids. I guess each scheduler is creating a long running task or thread pool thread which it is keeping for the duration of the observable.

Comment: Yeah it could be the way `ObserveOn` works.  You could use `GroupByUntil(item => item.Key, group => group.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))` instead, which would cause keys (and their threads) to shut down whenever the key has not been seen recently (it will start back up if the key shows up again).

Comment: @Brandon What if the processing thread takes more than 30 seconds? `GroupByUntil` will complete the group causing the new element with the same key with high probability to run on a different thread.